# Possible number of L-tetrominoes in covering an $8 \times 8$ chessboard

Tags: discrete-mathematics, tiling

Assuming that we do not have T-tetrominoes in our play, what are the possible numbers of L-tetrominoes that can appear in a covering with tetrominoes?

I have proven that the number can be any even number, of course, there cannot be more than 16 since each tetromino has 4 grids and we have 64 grids.

I doubt the number can be odd but having a hard time proving it.
Any help?

[Picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/All_5_free_tetrominoes.svg/1280px-All_5_free_tetrominoes.svg.png) for all types of tetrominoes (Omitting T-tetromino):

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you mean by covering, if you have fewer than $16$ you cannot cover the board by the area argument you give.  What do you mean by covering by fewer than $16$ pieces?

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry for the wording, any covering should consist of exactly 16 pieces.

Comment: Then what is your question?  You ask about other numbers.  You say you have proven it can be any even number, like $14$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can the number of L-tetrominoes in any covering be odd?

Comment: What do you mean by a covering?  Normally a covering requires covering all the squares of the chessboard exactly once.  The area says that only works with $16$.  Once we demonstrate a covering with $16$ we are done.  No other number can work.

Comment: What are T and L-tetrominoes?

Comment: @RossMillikan Extrapolate a bit: The chessboard is covered by tetrominoes, some of which might not be L-tetrominoes.

Comment: That should have been in the question.  It was what I was trying to understand.  It certainly sounded to me like we were only using L pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two L-tetrominoes can be used to cover a $2\times 4$ grid completely and a chessboard can be broken into such rectangles.

---

Color the columns of the $8\times 8$ chessboard alternatingly white and black.

The tetrominoes will cover the following number of colored squares in such a coloring.

$L$-tet covers $1\ W$, $3\ B$ or $3\ W,1\ B$.

$\mathrm{Straight}$-tet covers $4\ B/W$ or $2\ B,2\ W$

$\mathrm{Square}$-tet covers $2\ B,2\ W$.

$\mathrm{Skew}$-tet covers $2\ B,2\ W$.

Since the number of white and black squares to be colored will be $32$ each, there can't be an odd number of $L$-tetrominoes because they will cover an odd number of black, white squares.

Every other even number $0 \le n=2k \le 16$ is possible. Just cover $k$ '$2 \times 4$ grids' with them and arrange.

Comment: Yes, I include this idea in my proof of the number of $L$ being even, I picked it up again  and I think I got it.